# one key multiple values from different sources c#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am trying to make a c# program that will compare two files for me, and tell me the differences of specific parts. I have been able to get the parts I need into variables while looping through, but I now want to add these to a key with 3 values per file, so a key with 6 values overall which I will then compare to eachother later on. But I can only add 3 values at a time using the loop I have, so I need to be able to add the last 3 values to the key without overwriting the first 3.

example of data from file:

```
[\Advanced\Rules\Correlation Rules\Suspect_portscan\];
CheckDescription    =S  Detect Port scans;
Enabled =B  0;
Priority    =L  3;
```

I have managed to get what I need into variables so I have:
string SigName would be "Suspect_portscan"
Int Enabled, Priority, Blocking as 0 3 and null respectivly.

I then want to make a dictionary type thing, with a key which would be the SigName and the first 3 values as enabled, priority, blocking.
Then when looping through the second file, I want to add the 2nd files settings for the enabled, priority, blocking for the same SigName (so to the key) in the last 3 value slots.

I will then compare this against itself, like 'if signame(0) != signame(3)' so if file 1 enabled is not the same as file two enabled make a note and tell me.

But the problem I have is not being able to get the data into a dictionary or lookup, I'm completely stumped. It seems like I should use a dictionary with a list for the values but I cant get it working on the second loop through.

Thanks.

Code:

```
     static void Main()
    {
        Dictionary<string, List<int>> PolicyDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>(); 
        int Counter = 0, TempCounter = 0;
        String[] PolicyOne = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"filepath");
        string[] PolicyTwo = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"filepath2");

        foreach (string lines in PolicyOne)
        {
            if ((lines.Contains("CheckDescription")) && (!lines.Contains("userdefined network event template")))
            {//if true do this
                TempCounter = Counter;

                int FirstSlashes = (PolicyOne[(TempCounter - 1)]).IndexOf(@"\", 28);
                int LastSlashes = (PolicyOne[(TempCounter - 1)]).LastIndexOf(@"\");
                string SigName = (PolicyOne[(TempCounter - 1)]).Substring(FirstSlashes+1,(LastSlashes-FirstSlashes)-1);

               Char Enabled = (PolicyOne[(TempCounter + 1)])[(PolicyOne[(TempCounter + 1)]).Length - 2];
               Char Priority = (PolicyOne[(TempCounter + 2)])[(PolicyOne[(TempCounter + 2)]).Length - 2];
               Char Blocking = (PolicyOne[(TempCounter + 3)])[(PolicyOne[(TempCounter + 3)]).Length-2];

               PolicyDictionary[SigName] = new List<int> {Enabled,Priority,Blocking};



            }
           // end if
            Counter++;
        }
        // end for each

        foreach (string lines in PolicyTwo)
        {
            if ((lines.Contains("CheckDescription")) && (!lines.Contains("userdefined network event template")))
            {//if true do this
                Counter = 0;
                TempCounter = Counter;

                int FirstSlashes = (PolicyTwo[(TempCounter - 1)]).IndexOf(@"\", 28);
                int LastSlashes = (PolicyTwo[(TempCounter - 1)]).LastIndexOf(@"\");
                string SigName = (PolicyTwo[(TempCounter - 1)]).Substring(FirstSlashes + 1, (LastSlashes - FirstSlashes) - 1);

                Char Enabled = (PolicyTwo[(TempCounter + 1)])[(PolicyOne[(TempCounter + 1)]).Length - 2];
                Char Priority = (PolicyTwo[(TempCounter + 2)])[(PolicyOne[(TempCounter + 2)]).Length - 2];
                Char Blocking = (PolicyTwo[(TempCounter + 3)])[(PolicyOne[(TempCounter + 3)]).Length - 2];

                // here I will just end up overwriting it, but im not sure how to get arround this.
                PolicyDictionary[SigName] = new List<int> { Enabled, Priority, Blocking };


            }
            // end if
            Counter++;
        }
        // end for each

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I grasp what you're trying to do, but a code sample might help.

It sounds like you need to create a type for the values you want to store.

e.g.

```
public class FileContent
{
  public char Enabled {get; set;}
  public string Priority {get; set;}
  public string SigName {get; set; 

 /*whatever else you need*/
}
```

You can then create two instances of this type from each file (or many files). If you want to compare specific properties you can. If you need to store in a dictionary you can.

Alternatively you can override Equals(), or implement IEquatable to enable type comparison.

That is, of course, presuming I understand the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I understand what you mean here. Will research more and see what I can do. Still new to c# so dont fully understand all these little parts yet. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Since I have no idea what your code is like at the moment and i only have your description to go by, i would suggest something like this

```
public class FileData
{
  public int Enabled {get; set;}
  public int Priority {get; set;}
  public int Blocking {get; set;}
}
```

Then create two dictionaries

```
var File1 = new Dictionary<string, Filedata>();
var File2 = new Dictionary<string, Filedata>();
```

Fill those two up while going through your two files, your SigName being the key (string) for your dictionaries

The compare them like so:

```
foreach (var item in File1)
{
  var file1Data = item.Value;
  var file2Data = file2[item.Key];
  if (file1Data.Enabled != file2Data.Enabled)
  {
     // do what you want
  }
}
```

Comment: Thats a very neat idea, thanks alot. My brain says that would be spot on. Amazing how hours of thinking I cant come up with that, and you all just pluck these out your brains! thankyou.

Comment: practice, practice (another way of saying, some of us are getting old :P )